# Array reference in Stata?

Tags: stata

I need a Stata code similar to this SAS code:

```
i=1; 
do while (i <= 6);
    A=B(C(i));
    i=i+1;
end;
```

Both B and C are arrays as

```
B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5 and B_6
C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5 and C_6
```

For example, if `i` = `1`, then `C(i)` = `C_1`.

For row 3, if `C_1` = `5`, then I want to set `A` to `B_5`.

my problem is with accessing the array entry `B(C(i))`.  How can I write this access in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a one-to-one equivalent. See

FAQ     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Implementing SAS-like ARRAYs in Stata
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . W. Gould
        2/03    How do I implement SAS-like ARRAYs in Stata?

[Here is a link.](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/implement-sas-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little clumsy, but (insofar as I understand the question) it does what you are asking for:

```
clear all
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    scalar c_`i' = 7-`i'
}
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    scalar b_`i' = ceil(100/`i')
}

// test method
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    scalar a = b_`=c_`i''
    di a
}
scalar list
```

Note that as you've written the question, `a` is overwritten each time, so presumably there are commands following "`a = b(c(i))`". The Stata syntax `'=...'` (with a proper opening single quote) evaluates the scalar `c_'i'` and inserts the resulting value in the name for `b_?`, which `a` is then set equal to.

Comment: I guess you have answered the question as the OP might like, so fine, but the implication in turn is why one would loop when you can work with vectors and matrices, not scalars.

Comment: Well, the scalar approach was for illustration only (lacking a reproducible example from the OP), but I (naturally) agree that there are better ways of approaching the problem.

Comment: My experience with SAS arrays suggests that B_1, ..., B_6, C_1, ..., C_6 are all variable names, so (without looping over observations) scalars do not yield the desired results. What is requested, I think, is a straightforward way to use the value of a variable to choose from among several other variables. The choice of example names obscured this. In SAS the array C could consist of variables frog, newt, toad, prince, pauper, and knave, so C(3) would be the value of toad, and B(C(3)) would be the value of the toad'th variable in the B array.